# Hide textbox value if the value is 0

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

How to hide the value in textbox if the value is 0 ?

I dont want to hide the textbox, just hide the value if the value is 0.

```
<input type=number value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function valChange(obj){
  if(obj.value=="0"){
    obj.style.color="#fff"
  } else{
    obj.style.color="#000"
  }
}
```

```css
input[value="0"] { color: #fff; }
```

```html
<input id="num" type=number value="0" onchange="valChange(this);"/>
```

Comment: I love this answer. My reflex action was to do it with JS. BUT It should work but doesnt seem to in Chrome 88. The input text is always `#fff`.

Comment: Thank You, but this also make other number not visible

Comment: Ah it's because the value doesnt update in the DOM when the input changes. Might have to use JS...

Comment: Can u show me how to do it ? Sorry I'm new to web dev

Comment: @wanprogrammer Done Please try now

Comment: Thank You @camaulay I thought that will work with CSS but it was not when I posted. Learn something new

Comment: Great but if i want to use the value 0 elsewhere and I want to show it, they will also hide :(

Comment: No that will not hide

Answer (score 0):

This solutions uses a JavaScript event listener to listen for changes on the input. Every time the value changes it checks this value and if it equals 0 then it sets the color of the input to transparent and when it doesn't it sets it back to the initial value.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.currentTarget.value == 0) {
    e.currentTarget.style.color = 'transparent'
  } else {
    e.currentTarget.style.color = 'initial'
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends slightly on how you are storing the value of the input. But essentially you can do something like this:

```
<input type="number" value={inputNumber ? inputNumber : NaN} />
```

You can use "" or null instead of NaN, depending on your use of inputNumber and initialize inputNumber to 0 when starting.

This works because when inputNumber is 0, it is falsy and so NaN (or "" or null) will be received by the input, which results in nothing being shown.

Comment: setting up NaN can cause very big problem.

Comment: Did u mean like this
<input type="number" value={0? 0: ""} />

Comment: I assumed the value in the input would change and therefore would need to be stored in a variable. The way you put it, the value will always be 0 and therefore won't ever show up.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution.

Using the ternary operator you can easily achieve that.

```js
$("#txt").val($("#txt").val() === "0" ? "" : $("#txt").val());
$('#txt').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
  $("#txt").val($("#txt").val() === "0" ? "" : $("#txt").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="0" / id="txt">
```

Comment: It will work first time only second time it will not

Comment: what if I want to post or use this value somewhere else. He is just saying that hide the value

Comment: So basically this will make value to null ?

Comment: You always check the value for null?